Headset Bearings Help
The Goulash Cycle is back !
(Please bare with me, really new to cycling)
Okay I started tearing down the front of this same chrome train wreck of a  (unknown 29" mountain bike) And of course there's no bearings ..! I took some measurements and it shows it's threaded and I have a 28.4mm X a 9 3/4" steerer tube , head tube is 38.2mm , 29.5mm X 5.30".The headset measures 38.2mm with a rise 4.1mm ..... What did I do wrong ?
Please help with size needed for top and bottom.

It's hard to know how to be helpful with the information provided. Pictures of the parts might provide clues that would enable answers.
